# Many named Model on TDB or SDB at jena

Tags: java, rdf, jena

I'm developing an application that uses the Jena.
I want to use many named Model on TDB or SDB.
However, DataSource Class is has been removed.
In order to do this, I would not without the Model, only use the Graph and DatasetGraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Dataset`, the `DataSource`/`Dataset` split has been removed. `Dataset` now has the operations you need.

Comment: I was mistaken to Dataset is read-only.I had to manually edit the triples.Thank you.